# AngularJS Changing value with refreshing scope object on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My problem is that after clicking ng-click does not update {{homeCtrl.carCondition}} in view.
 
 Function from Class retrieved by import

```
checkVehicleCondition( brakesCondition ){
            let vehicle = this.brakesCondition;
            if ( vehicle === 0 ) {
                this.vehicleCondition = 'Poor';
                console.log(this.vehicleCondition);
            } else {
                this.vehicleCondition = 'Excellent';
                console.log(this.vehicleCondition);
            }
```

Controller

const myCar = new ClientCar( 'BMW X5' );

```
  this.carCondition = myCar.vehicleCondition;// Gives object from class to the view
```

```
  this.checkVehicle = myCar.checkVehicleCondition;;//Function Update vehicleCondition and should gives new value to "this.carCondition"
```

index.html

```
 <h3>Condition:{{homeCtrl.carCondition}}</h3></br>
    <input type="button" value="like"   ng-click="homeCtrl.checkVehicle()"></br></br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typo in the line

```
 ng-click="homeCtrl.checkVechicle()"></br>
```

should be

```
 ng-click="homeCtrl.checkVehicle()"></br>
```

and not sure you are actually calling the function - it is "checkVehicleCondition( brakesCondition )"...

shouldn't the function call be  ng-click="homeCtrl.checkVehicleCondition()">... with some value of the brakes condition being passed to the function?

and another typo....

```
this.checkVechicle = myCar.checkVehicleCondition;
```

should be

```
this.checkVehicle = myCar.checkVehicleCondition;
```

also another in the following -

```
vale="like"
```

should be

```
value="like"
```

Comment: "brakesCondition" are already assigned .My problem is with not refreshing carCondition $scope  value is assigned(consol.log) only not refreshed in view

Comment: The solution was to remove "use strict"; idk why but it work's